# Create a pipe delimited, double quote qualified csv file using SSRS?

Tags: csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a scheduled daily report in csv format with pipe separators and double quote text qualifiers.  The data is taken from a Microsoft SQL view.  I have been attempting to do this with SSRS and created a custom extension which i had hoped would do the job -

```
        <Extension Name="CSVPIPE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.CsvRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.CsvRendering">
            <OverrideNames>
                <Name Language="en-US">CSV (Pipe delimited)</Name>
            </OverrideNames>
            <Configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <FieldDelimiter>|</FieldDelimiter>
                    <Qualifier>"</Qualifier>
                    <FieldDelimiter xml:space="preserve">&#09;</FieldDelimiter>
                    <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
```

Unfortunately this does not add the "text qualifier" to the file so I looked at a number of ways to try and either fix this in SSRS or change the file created by SSRS retrospectively. What seemed like such a simple task has proved far more challenging than I anticipated and after many wasted hours, my tether has reached it's end.  Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is it an option to modify the view to return the data with the text qualifiers instead? Then you can use this Pipe delimited output to achieve the end result..

Comment: Unfortunately not an option due to various complications with field types.  I can add the quotes to the field in SSRS using =chr(34) & Fields!CLIENTURN.Value & chr(34) but then when I export I end up with 3 sets of double quotes around the field.

Comment: have you tried &quot; instead of " on the field delimiter field of your custom extension?

Comment: i mean on your qualifier element of your custom extension xml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jayvee, but that did not work either :-(